# Two different SQL Server with same collation show same decimal field in two different ways

Tags: sql-server, decimal, collation

I have 2 different SQL Server installations with the same collation, "Latin1_General_CI_AS".
The 2 instances have same database, with same tables and same fields.

One of the field is a Decimal(18,4), and if in Sql Server Managment I show the records of the table, I see 2 different values.
In one instance I see a "comma" for the decimal separator, in the other one I see "dot" for the decimal separator.

Something like this:

```
124.4500
124,4500
```

The command:

```
SELECT @@Language
```

is the same for both instances ("us_english").

I do not know why I get 2 different values for the same field of the same table.

Comment: numeric data types don't use a collation

Comment: Check if different regional settings are being used in the Server OS

Comment: This is a client setting, the server only knows decimal points. Check the server OS as Peter suggested, or your sql client options.

Comment: It was the Server OS setting, thanks for the reply

Answer (score 0):

Likely the account you are using to connect is not defined at same way on both the instances.

I had similar issue with the same server by connecting with two different accounts. In my case the default language was set to "default" instead than "Italian" for one of the two accounts so only one of them was using the value from the global @@Language .
I also noticed that this kind of setting, in case you are working with ODBC, can be overridden at DNS level, in the same windows where you can specify the Database.